# Visual Studio .NET copy a file and all related Using/dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am working on Visual Studio solution that has many services in a single project.

To organize better the code, I am trying to separate it in different isolated projects.

The idea is that I will start the separation by the controllers, and I am looking for a way to copy all the dependencies files of a given controller recursively into the new project. This might lead some duplication but I am fine with it as far as I have better separation.

So far I have done this manually, by copying the controller, and all the related `using namespaces` files, but it is an exhaustive and long process.

Is there a better way to do this, or any tool that could speed up this?

Comment: A simpler approach would be to start from the opposite side. Take the layer with the least dependencies (like models, database, or basic services at the very bottom) and extract those out. If you try to extract the topmost layer (api controllers), then you'll have to bring along all the dependencies down to the last layer, and won't achieve what you want.

Comment: @Orion Thanks for the idea. the problem is that I am not familiar with this project, and I do not know which models are used for the part I am extacting (and there are a lot of models)

Comment: A common practice is to have 3 "layers" with all the web specific stuff at the top, layer 2 is the service layer with all of the business logic, and layer 3 is the repository layer. Take a look at [Common web application architectures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures) for ideas

Comment: @albanx Browse the code starting with a random API controller. See what services it calls and browse to their classes. If those services call further services, recursively drill down to them. When you arrive at a class that doesn't call any further classes, you reached the lowest point in the abstraction and you can start your extracting from it.

Comment: @Orion it is exactly what I am doing, but requires a lot lot of manual work and time

Comment: @albanx You said you're copying the controller and all the related dependencies with it. I'm suggesting you to start from the other side - extract only the bottom-most dependencies into separate projects first.

Comment: What kind of C# web project are you using? Such as which template project to get start with?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT it is .net standard web project, which has many "areas" in it. I am trying to extract one of the areas into a separate project (in SDK style with Nuget). Right now the process is just copy paste, adapt dependencies.